# SQL query convert today date into yyyymmdd

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

We have a SQL Server 2000 database for our business. Now I'm trying to make an easy to use and readable output for our staff. The SQL query I made works fine, but as said I want to make it easy to use. So that our employee only has to press an update button and he or she receives the actual numbers.

The database uses on every record an `UPD_DAT` column containing to actual date that record is made. But in a `YYYYMMDD` format. So for today it is `20170512`. So far so good. Now I want to use today as query. So I googled and tried something with `Datepart` and `getdate`. But somehow it won't work.

So I get something like that:

```
SELECT data 
FROM table 
WHERE UPD_DAT = (DATEPART("YYYY", (GETDATE())) * 100 +  
                 DATEPART("MM", MONTH(GETDATE()))) * 100 +  
                 DATEPART("DD", (GETDATE()))
```

I started in January whit this query and thought that it's working. Today I continued whit it and noticed some problems. The result I get is in January not in may, I get `20170112` instead of `20170512`.

As mentioned it is SQL Server 2000.

Comment: You don't need `datepart("MM"` just use `MONTH(GETDATE()))*100`

Comment: what is the datatype of UPD_DAT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query,

```
select data from table where CAST(UPD_DAT AS NVARCHAR(10)) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GetDate(),112)
```

Answer (score 0):

dont use month and datepart function together.

I mean dont use this `select datepart("mm", month(GETDATE()))`

use the following to get the date in your desired format

```
select Datepart("YYYY",(GETDATE())) , datepart("mm",GETDATE()),  DATEPART("DD",(GETDATE()))
```